# A boy is reincarnated into a novel world as normal person, but becomes strong because he knows the story

Tags: story-identification, manga

The main character reincarnated into some normal person but because he knew how story went, he looked for some secret dungeon to make himself stronger.

At some point the main character went to an academy. He met a boy who was to be a hero in the future. There is an event - fighting with others in some arena. The top two were the main character and the hero.

Unexpectedly, a female leader of some secret organization went to see the fight. The main character knows the female leader because, in the story, the female leader invited the hero to join the organization. Because the main character is strong, the female leader took a liking to the main character, rather than the hero.

The main character went to a secret dungeon. He got a powder that is needed for another item to make a hero sword. The main character tried to find a way to give the powder to the hero. He meets the hero and asks if the hero wants to go to some place. The hero asks the main character how he knows. Then the main character asks if the hero would go along with him.

At another place, some evil people doing something in a dungeon. They split up to search. Accidentally two people who went another way meet the main character and the hero because the other dungeons are interconnected. Of course there will be fight.

Some people in a secret organization monitor the main character because the female leader did not want the main character dead. The evil people in the other dungeon are killed by the female leader of secret organization. The main character and the hero can defeat the enemy. The hero recognizes that the main character is stronger.

They went to see the prize for clearing the dungeon. The prize looked like a plant stem. The main character tells the hero that the plant stem can become a sword with other items. The main character tells the hero he has the item and gives the powder to hero.

Comment: Was this in full color or black and white? About what year did you read this?

Comment: in color, last month. forgot to make bookmark.

Answer (score 2):

**The Novel's extra (2022)**
[image]
Wouldn’t it be a dream to wake up in a world of your own creation? For Kim Hajin, it’s nothing short of a nightmare. With no clue how or why he’s been transported into his web novel — as a mere extra, no less! — Hajin has little choice but to see his story through until the end. Lucky for him, as the author, he knows this perilous world like the back of his hand. But when discrepancies in the plot begin popping up left and right, Hajin soon realizes that things aren’t quite so simple, after all…